# jQuery scrolling animation works, but window.location.hash screws it over

Tags: jquery, animation, window.location

Trying to solve this issue for 2 days now without success.

I have a main nav bar located in a single page website. The website has a scrolling animation.
Whenever the user clicks a link from the nav bar, the window.location.hash should change.

Now, the thing is that it USED to change. But at the same time, it had flickering issues (which I couldn't resolve with e.preventDefault()). The only way to stop the flickering was to add the stop() to the window.location.hash. 
So now I don't have the flickering but the window.location.hash doesn't change anymore, which isn't a good thing.

This is the code

```
<html>
<body>   <div class="nav">
    <ul class="floatRight">
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" data-to="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" data-to="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" data-to="#platform">Platform</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" data-to="#investors">Investors</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" data-to="#team">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" data-to="#newsPress">News & Press</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" data-to="#explained">Startup Explained</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript">    

function gotoAndScroll(to){
    if(typeof to == 'string') {
        var diff = (to == '#newsPress')? 74 : 83;
        $.scrollTo( {top: $(to).offset().top - diff}, 1500, {axis:'y',easing:'easeInOutCubic'});
    }
    else if(typeof to == 'number'){
        $.scrollTo({top:Number(to), left:0},{duration:1500});
    }
}

$('.nav a').click(function(e) {

    if($(this).data('to') != '#home')
        gotoAndScroll($(this).data('to'));
    else 
        gotoAndScroll(0);
        window.location.hash = $(this).data('to').stop();
});    

$('a#logo').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).data('to') != '#home')
        gotoAndScroll($(this).data('to'));
    else 
        gotoAndScroll(0);
        window.location.hash = $(this).data('to').stop();
});    

</script>    

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:

When clicking one of the nav links, I get the next error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #about has no method 'stop' 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

I realize that stop() shouldn't be there, but, against all logic, that's the only thing that fixes the flickering.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? :/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error? And what does the function `gotoAndScroll()` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your `a` tags as they give an error because of the `return false`.
So change them from `href="javascript: void(0); return false;"` to `href="javascript: void(0);"` that will do the same (not use the `href`).

Further remove the `window.location.hash = $(this).data('to').stop();` out of the click functions and add it to your `gotoAndScroll()` function like this :

```
function gotoAndScroll(to){
    if(typeof to == 'string') {
        var diff = (to == '#newsPress')? 74 : 83;
        $.scrollTo( {top: $(to).offset().top - diff}, 1500, {axis:'y',easing:'easeInOutCubic'});
        // Added this line because you always call this function so you could have it in one place.
        window.location.hash = to;

    }
    else if(typeof to == 'number'){
        $.scrollTo({top:Number(to), left:0},{duration:1500});
    }
}
```

I have removed the `stop()` from the `$(this).data('to').stop()` because you can't call `stop` on a string (data('to') is a string).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although this code does exactly what I'm trying to avoid. 
While it does update the window.location.hash, it still makes the page flicker every time I click on one of the nav links. :(

Comment: What do you mean by flicker? Do you have an example (Fiddle)? What browser are you using? (On Chrome it all runs smooth).

Comment: By flicker, I mean the page is displaying the target anchor (where its supposed to scroll to) for less than a second, and then actually scrolls to it.

I've tried fixing that with e.preventDefault(), but after that didn't work, the only chance I had left was the stop() function.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.hash = to` is only inside else scope, which only runs if (to == "#home")

you have to call stop() on the element being animated, say "$":

```
$('.nav a').click(function(e) {

    if($(this).data('to') != '#home')
        gotoAndScroll($(this).data('to'));
    else 
        gotoAndScroll(0);
        $.stop();
    window.location.hash = $(this).data('to');
});    

$('a#logo').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).data('to') != '#home')
        gotoAndScroll($(this).data('to'));
    else 
        gotoAndScroll(0);
        $.stop();
    window.location.hash = $(this).data('to');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but with this code, the window.location.hash still doesn't update.